# Add a side-effect to a function in a generic way

Tags: kotlin, generics, lambda, delegation, side-effects

How can I write a Kotlin generic function that takes a function as an argument and adds a side-effect to it? For instance,

```
fun something(one: Int, two: String): String { return "${one}, ${two}" }
fun somethingElse(arg: Array<String>): String { return "${arg}" }

val w1 = wrapped(::something)
w1(42, "hello")

val w2 = wrapped(::somethingElse)
w2(arrayOf("ichi", "ni"))
```

The following works for functions that take only a single parameter:

```
fun <A, R> wrapped(theFun: (a: A) -> R): (a: A) -> R {
    return { a: A ->
        theFun(a).also { println("wrapped: result is $it") }
    }
}
```

To make this work with an arbitrary number of arguments, I'd need some construct that gives me the type of the argument list. Unfortunately, the Function generic can't be used since it takes only one parameter. The following does not compile:

```
fun <A, R> wrapped(theFun: Function<A, R>): Function<A, R> {
    return { args: A ->
        theFun(*args).also { println("wrapped: result is ${it}") }
    }
}
```

Or maybe I could use `varargs`? Does not seem to work with lambdas. Or Kotlin reflection?

Comment: Only possible with reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using reflection:

```kotlin
class KFunctionWithSideEffect<R>(private val f: KFunction<R>, private val sideEffect: (R) -> Unit) : KFunction<R> by f {
    override fun call(vararg args: Any?) = f.call(*args).also { sideEffect(it) }

    override fun callBy(args: Map<KParameter, Any?>) = f.callBy(args).also { sideEffect(it) }
}

fun <R> wrapped(theFun: KFunction<R>, sideEffect: (R) -> Unit = { str -> println("wrapped: result is $str") }) =
    KFunctionWithSideEffect(theFun, sideEffect)
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val w1 = wrapped(::something)
w1.call(42, "hello")

val w2 = wrapped(::somethingElse)
w2.call(arrayOf("ichi", "ni"))
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Although it looks pretty horrible. Kind of sad that this kind of thing is very easily done in TypeScript, but not in Kotlin.